# C# EWS Exchange API => sometimes work

Tags: c#, api, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, unauthorized

I've seen loads post on this forum about exchange API, but I've never found something like I have.

I' m trying to connect to Exchange using Exchange API in order to get all room's meetings. 
My problem : Sometimes, it's working, I can connect and get all my informations. And 5m later, impossible to connect. I got Unauthorized.
It's not an error on code because it's working, I think it's a problem with exchange server, but I really don't know what it is...

On the next picture, there are traces.
On the left, when it's working, And the same 30m later (same identification, same room) which is not working.

http://hpics.li/2d9b216

If you have any ideas ? I really don't know what to do.
thanks (and sorry for my english !)

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the working request comes from server A (look at the value of X-FEServer header), and the failing one comes from server B. Perhaps there is a configuration problem on server B.

Answer (score 0):

thx for this.

I've done some tests : I've modified my host file in my computer. when the url is pointing to serveur A, it's working. When it's on the other server, not working. It's the same configuration on both, cannot find what's wrong. So I will conserve my actual host file (pointing always on serveur A).